# input char* without using string library

Tags: c++, iostream, null-terminated

I'd like to do the following, but without including string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string s1,s2;
char c;
cout<<"input a string: "<<endl;
cin>>s1;
cout<<"input a character: "<<endl;
cin>>c;
cout<<"input another string: "<<endl;
cin>>s2;
}
```

When I try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char s1[128], s2[128];
char c;
cout << "input a string: " << endl;
cin.getline(s1, 128);
cout << "input a character: " << endl;
cin >> c;
cout << "input another string: " << endl;
cin.getline(s2, 128);
}
```

I run into issues... basically when I enter the character it also enters for the second string, and I never get a chance to enter it. please help thanks.

Rik

Comment: " but without including string" - why?

Comment: to learn how it works

Comment: The problem seems to be very obvious. Neither the first nor the second code chunk is valid C++, and no self-respecting C++ compiler will accept the code without errors. Neither of them comply with the requirements for a [mcve] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: forgot to put main in there, is that what you are talking about sam? it compiles fine

Comment: @Rik *to learn how it works* -- I see no attempt in creating a string class.

Comment: It is semi-obvious. It took longer to find the duplicate answer than to realize what was going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use cin.get() after use "cin >> var". This method extract symbol new line from buffe

Comment: While not the best answer this answer's not -2  bad.